# uploading a PDF in grails

Tags: grails, file-upload, upload, gsp

I need to upload a `PDF` in `grails` I have looked in texts and online. This is what I have so far in my controller

```
def upload = {
    def f = request.getFile('myFile')
    if(!f.empty) {
        f.transferTo( new File('/some/local/dir/myfile.txt') )
        response.sendError(200,'Done');
    } else {
        flash.message = 'file cannot be empty'
        render(view:'uploadForm')
    }
}
```

In the view I have this in the _forms view

```
    <g: uploadForm action="upload">
<input type="file" name="myFile"/>
<input type= "submit" value="Upload"/>
</g: uploadForm>
```

When I go to the create page to I get an error.

I get this error
Grails tag [g:] was not closed. Stacktrace follows:

```
Message: Error processing GroovyPageView: Grails tag [g:] was not closed
Line | Method
->>  461 | doFilter  in \grails-app\views\report\create.gsp

Caused by GrailsTagException: Grails tag [g:] was not closed
->>   36 | doCall    in C:/Users/Owner/Desktop/grails-app/views/report/create.gsp
```

Any suggestion on how to clear the error?  When I delete the addition to the _forms view the error goes. I can't see the unclosed tag

Full gsp as asked for

```
<div class="fieldcontain ${hasErrors(bean: reportInstance, field: 'location', 'error')} required">
    <label for="location">
        <g:message code="report.location.label" default="Location" />
        <span class="required-indicator">*</span>
    </label>
    <g:select id="location" name="location.id" from="${lc.Location.list()}" optionKey="id" required="" value="${reportInstance?.location?.id}" class="many-to-one"/>
</div>

<div class="fieldcontain ${hasErrors(bean: reportInstance, field: 'published', 'error')} required">
    <label for="published">
        <g:message code="report.published.label" default="Published" />
        <span class="required-indicator">*</span>
    </label>
    <g:datePicker name="published" precision="day"  value="${reportInstance?.published}"  />
</div>

<div class="fieldcontain ${hasErrors(bean: reportInstance, field: 'title', 'error')} ">
    <label for="title">
        <g:message code="report.title.label" default="Title" />

    </label>
    <g:textField name="title" value="${reportInstance?.title}"/>
</div>

<div class="fieldcontain ${hasErrors(bean: reportInstance, field: 'myFile', 'error')} ">
    <label for="myFile">
        <g:uploadForm action="upload"/>
    <input type="file" name="myFile"/>
    <input type= "submit" value="Upload"/>
    </g:uploadForm>

    </label>
</div>
```

Comment: In the question it is clearly seen there is a whitespace in uploadForm tag after `<g:` and `</g:`. Is that true?

Comment: thanks for the response and sorry for the delay.  Yes there is a white space.  I will get rid of it and see what happens

Comment: white space removed, project cleaned and rebooted and still the same error

Comment: You have other bad formatted view. Check no space after g: and that every tag is correctly closed.

Comment: <div class="fieldcontain ${hasErrors(bean: reportInstance, field: 'myFile', 'error')} ">
 <label for="myFile">
  <g:uploadForm action="upload"/>
 <input type="file" name="myFile"/>
 <input type= "submit" value="Upload"/>
 </g:uploadForm>
 
 </label>

Comment: Is everything that is there.  I can't seem to see the issue.  If I erase the div and the label it still trows the error

Comment: Full GSP add as requested.  It is at the bottom of the post

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove `/` from

```
<g:uploadForm action="upload"/>
```

This should be

```
<g:uploadForm action="upload">
    ....
</g:uploadForm>
```